# Params contain an array that wants to be a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, parameters

I have an array (coming from a `file_field, :multiple => true`) in my `params` that I want to turn into a hash so I can build associated models for each element and process in my create action.

Currently receiving:

```
{"gallery"=>{"name"=>"A Gallery", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>[#<1st Image data removed for brevity>, #<2nd Image data removed for brevity>]}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

I'd like to turn it into something like:

```
{"gallery"=>{"name"=>"A Gallery", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<1st Image data removed for brevity>}, "1"=>{"image"=>#<1st Image data removed for brevity>}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

considered something like this but it's clearly wrong:

```
i = 0
params[:gallery][:photos_attributes]["0"][:image].reduce({}) do |result, element|
  result[i++.to_s] = element
end
```

What's the "Rail's Way"?

Comment: (Not an answer) There is no i++ in ruby. Use i += 1 .

Comment: thanks, but that's the least of my worries... ;-)  even `result[i.to_s] = element` doesn't work: `undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum`.  Nor does: `result.merge!( { i.to_s => element } )` <sigh>

Comment: steenslag, in the context of this, one might want to use Numeric#incr! instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result hash at the end of each iteration.

```
i = 0
params[:gallery][:photos_attributes]["0"][:image].reduce({}) do |result, element|
  result[(i += 1).to_s] = element
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar when receiving data from an iOS device.  But, if I understand what you want and what your model(s) look like, to get nested attributes to work you don't want it to look like:

```
{ "photos_attributes" => { "0" => <image1>, "1" => <image2>, ... }
```

You want it to look like:

```
{ "photos_attributes" => [ <image1>, <image2>, ... ] }
```

And to do that all you need to do is:

```
params["gallery"]["photos_attributes"] = params["gallery"]["photos_attributes"]["0"]["image"]
```

Now, if I've misunderstood what you need, to get what you've asked for what you have might work (I don't use much `reduce` aka `inject`) or you could use tap:

```
i = 0
params["gallery"]["photos_attributes"] = {}.tap do |hash|
  params["gallery"]["photos_attributes"]["0"]["image"].each do |image|
    hash[i.to_s] = image
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

Not a whole lot better IMO.